# Can oracle plsql read an excel file attachment from mail

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

I want to know whether it is possible to read excel attachment(.xlsx) with multiple worksheet from mail directly into SQL table?
(as we do in external tables where .csv file is kept in FTP and then data is available in tables)
If yes then how can one achieve that.

Comment: I am afraid that in order to provide a decent answer we need some more context.
From what you write I would guess that you can get the work done using:<br/>
1. a piece of code that dumps the xlsx files in a file system accessible to Oracle<br/>
2. a scheduled jobs that checks whether there are new files to ingest<br/>
3. a java stored procedure that reads and dumps the file in the DB<br/>

Comment: [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/products/pl-sql-developer/) specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible? Everything is possible... given enough time, money and effort.

(Well, almost everything)

Though, I don't think it will be very easy task.

Some Hints:

To read an mail from oracle, you could use `EMAIL_CLIENT` package
http://plsqlmailclient.sourceforge.net/

To process the excel you could try using Anton Scheffer's `plsql`:

https://technology.amis.nl/2013/01/19/read-a-excel-xlsx-with-plsql

Alternatively I guess you could use `java` to process excel's contents.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the CSV file or XLSX file into a `BLOB`, you can then use the [APEX_DATA_PARSER](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/aeapi/PARSE-Function.html#GUID-B815CF74-C469-4F78-9433-643D1339E930) package to read the file as if it was a regular table.  The package was introduced in APEX 19.1 so any version after that has it.

If you do not have APEX installed into your database, I would highly recommend it. Even if you do not use APEX for the UI of your application, there are many PL/SQL utilities that get installed with APEX that are helpful for general use such as this.